# Get input whilst looping code

Tags: python, loops

I currently have a Twitter bot that streams tweets from Twitter in my timeline. Regardless of what it does, how could I also send Tweets (get keyboard input) at the same time as receiving Tweets (looping code).

This isn't a question about the Twitter API, just a general question on how to get input while looping code.

Comment: It depends on your needs. Basically you can do two things (at least) things: 1. Put both tasks inside one loop; 2. Run two separate threads.

Comment: Threading is your friend.

Comment: So non blocking input?

Comment: Hmm.. I've never tried threading. Is it really that pragmatic of a way to do it? It doesn't seem like it to me, but of course, (like I said) I've never tried it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you don't want your loop to wait for you to enter a tweet in each iteration, so you can't use the most common method raw_input.

In this case, it is platform specific. For Unix systems, you should use the [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module, while in Windows, you have the [msvcrt](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/msvcrt-console.html) one.

With select, the idea is to check stdin inside every iteration, and process the message when you get one.

Something like:

```
import sys
import select

while True:
    message = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout=0.1)[0]
    if message:
        print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this out. I'll select this as an answer for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a specific thread for it, when used would call your Twitter API post function. (But it depends how your code is structured)

```
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target=post_from_keyboard)
t1.start()
t1.join()   

# Loop exits when users writes quit. 
# Obviously it won't post any Tweets with the word "quit"    
def post_from_keyboard():
    while(True):   
        kb_tweet = input("Enter Tweet or write "quit" to exit")
        if kb_tweet != "quit"
            your_tweet_api_call( kb_tweet )
        else:
            break
```

Comment: `while(True)` is infinite loop, so when to break from it?

Comment: Since it's to be included in a bot I'm assuming in never stops. EDIT: updated the code so it quits. It's not very pythonistic but allows exit from loop

Comment: Especially unpythonic with that semicolon at the end.

Comment: Sorry for assuming things without trying the code out, but. This doesn't seem to solve my problem. I do not want it to wait for an input. I want it to keep looping forever, and if I want to, I can also send a tweet (get input). This will wait for you to type something before continuing with the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps,you are looking for something like this

```
userInput = raw_input()

while(userInput != q):
    #do something
    userInput = raw_input()
```

Comment: No, I would not be able to run other code whilst it is waiting for input. It will wait for me to type something and press enter before continuing in the loop.